# How to retrieve scheduled Hangout on Air contents using php?

Tags: php, google-plus, google-hangouts

I am trying to create an php application, from this I want to retrieve the hangout on air data and display it in my php application and also I want to retrieve only hangout on air content not any other content like photos or videos shared in a google plus profile. Is it possible to retrieve full contents of a scheduled hangout on air(which are public) using php?